# dwm and screen lock

Tags: linux, dwm

I recently made the switch to dwm as the default window-manager on my laptop. It being a no frills software, I had to configure a few things that I usually don't have to worry about.

While I got most things to work, I can't seem to figure out a foolproof way to lock the screen on the laptop. Currently, I have a partially working solution using a program called `xautolock`. Which manages to lock the screen after a specified timeout. But it fails to lock the screen after wake-up. Which is important to me.

```
 xautolock -time 10 -locker slock
```

Any ideas?

Comment: have you tried `xssstate` or `xss` (links available on suckless.org)

Comment: If you use systemd, you can have a service file that locks the screen on wakeup.

Comment: and if you don't use systemd, you can run a script on suspend/hibernate using the `pm-utils` package.

Comment: @jasonwryan   Yup. Creating a systemd service fixed the problem.

Comment: You should post your service as an answer and accept it: it will help someone else who stumbles on this via a search.

Comment: @PinkFloyd it's only turning on screensaver after sometime, I actually would like to have screen locked after closing a lid only or activating it manually. I have reasons not to want screensaver after sometime of inactivity :)

Answer (score 2):

You can use xss-lock and it works without a systemd unit. It listens to DPMS as well.

You can add these lines to your *$HOME/.xinitrc* right before starting dwm.

```bsh
xset dpms 180 &
xss-lock -- slock &
exec dwm
```

Comment: Welcome to the site. You may want to add some explanation on where these commands shoud be located, so that users reading your answer know more easily how to apply it.

Answer (score 1):

Creating a separate systemd service seems like a clean way to solve the problem. Also on a system running `sysinit` one can launch slock using suspend/resume hooks.

```
[Unit]
Description=Lock the screen on resume from suspend

[Service]
User=jason
Environment=DISPLAY=:0
ExecStart=/usr/bin/slock

[Install]
WantedBy=suspend.target
```

Comment: Nice username :)

Answer (score 0):

You can use suckless's own lock tool called slock. it in my opinion is the best paring with dwm because it has the same minimalist design. you can download the source code from here: https://tools.suckless.org/slock/

all you need to do after is go in to the config.h file and change:

```
static const char *user  = "nobody";
static const char *group = "nogroup";
```

To this:

```
static const char *user  = "<USERNAME>";
static const char *group = "wheel";
```

Change  to your username of computer.